# 2 many to one relationship

Tags: grails, data-structures, orm, foreign-key-relationship

hi ave to relate 3 table one to many:

this is the concept table1(1) -> (N)table2(1) -> (N)table3

I've tried this, but hi have some issue in compile the code:

```
class 1 {
static hasMany = [two : 2]
}

class 2 {

static belongsTo = [ one : 1]
static hasMany = [three : 3]

}

class 3 {
static belongsTo = [two: 2 ]
}
```

If I put the belongs to under the has many in tab 2 and then i check the db i see that grails understand that as many to many relation.

The DB that I use is postgres

Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: What version of Grails are you running?

Comment: What do you mean by "some issue in compile". When you remove "belongsTo", do you get compilation errors?

Comment: i running the 2.3.4 , if i remove "belongsTo" i don't get error but many to many relation.

Comment: I created a project using the domain classes you provided and it is only generating 3 tables with the correct relationships (I only tested it against the in-memory H2 db).  It sounds like you may need to clean the project if you are getting compilation errors, and that may in turn fix your schema generation problem.  Try running `grails clean` _outside of interactive mode_ and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok now it work but now i get some problem with bootstrap, now i have to understand if this things are related, thank you very much!

Comment: Have the same with with 2.2.4 and if hasMany collection is List.